# import mapping dont save for custom fields on contact subtypes

Tags: custom-fields, import, data-import, field-mapping

As the title. 
If I create custom field set against a contact subtype, then import fields from a csv (saving the mapping for later use), none of the mapped fields are saved for the custom fieldset.

i.e.: on dmaster i can:

- create a new custom field set **contact subtype custom fields**:

  - for use on individual > Volunteer
- add field: **contact subtype field**
- find (or create) a volunteer, and enter something into the new custom field
- export the contact (select fields **Contact_id** & **contact subtype field** (& down load the file)
- import the file, mapping the fields correctly

  - downloaded file
  - update contacts
  - contact type = individual > subtype: Volunteer
  - continue
- set mapping to correctly map to the custom field **contact subtype field**

  - save mapping as... 'map 1'
  - continue
- continue with import
- done
- change the **contact subtype field** label in the csv to **foobar**
- import the csv - loading the saved mapping 'map 1'

mapping does not load + notice is thrown up onscreen:

```
Notice: Undefined index: in CRM_Import_ImportProcessor->loadSavedMapping() (line 451 of /srv/buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Import/ImportProcessor.php).
```

anyone else suffer with this problem or have any ideas?

there's an issue logged [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1662) that has a fix, and is most likely related, but I'm not sure if this is a separate issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks Marsh for reporting, I could replicated this on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ which is running on 5.25 tree.

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16957) for this issue. Can you please try applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16957.patch)?

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: That's wicked - thanks Pradeep. This all seems to work now - I can save mappings and they populate automatically - will post back here if I see any issues.

:D

Comment: Thanks Pradeep!

Comment: Can you mark this answered if it fixed your problem?